# What do the coordinates of accumulatedFrame means in SKShapeNode & how can I get them

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I tried to get the position of spriteNode that I call wallNode. It has SKShapeNode as a child and it is a child of my scene.

the wallNode init is as follow:

```
-(id) init:(CGPoint)firstPoint: (CGPoint)lastPoint{

if (self = [super init]) {

    self.name = @"wall";
    self.firstPoint = firstPoint;
    self.lastPoint = lastPoint;

    CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, self.firstPoint.x, self.firstPoint.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, self.lastPoint.x, self.lastPoint.y);

    _wallShape = [[SKShapeNode alloc ]init];
    _wallShape.path = CGPathCreateCopy(pathToDraw);
    _wallShape.strokeColor = [SKColor redColor];
    _wallShape.lineWidth = 15;

    SKTexture *texture = [[SKTexture alloc] init];
    SKPhysicsBody * physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:firstPoint toPoint: lastPoint] ;

    self.physicsBody = [self updatePhysicsBody:physicsBody :@"wallNode"];

    [self addChild: _wallShape];
}

return self;
}
```

when I use touch event to select the Wall and try to get its position as follow:

```
if([[ref getChoice] isEqualToString:@"Select"]){

        _positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

        AbstractNode * touchedNode = (AbstractNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:_positionInScene];

        if([touchedNode isMemberOfClass:[SKShapeNode class]]){

            touchedNode = (AbstractNode*) touchedNode.parent;

        }
NSLog(@"touchedNodeX: %f, touchedNodeY:", [touchedNode position].x, [touchedNode position].y);
```

It gives me position x= 0.0000, position Y= 0.0000. but when I debug I noticed the following

```
<SKShapeNode> name:'(null)' accumulatedFrame:{{0, 0}, {184, 386}}
```

I am sure that {184,386} is the position I'm looking for but I don't know how to get it programatically. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: A node’s accumulated frame  is the largest rectangle that includes the frame of the node and the frames of all its descendants.So the coordinates are those of the rectangle

Comment: you can use calculateAccumulatedFrame to get it programatically

Comment: @MithunMadhav: cld u please tell me how to do it please to get 184 and 386 separately.

Comment: i guess since it is a CGRect  , you can access the values as rect.frame.size.width and rect.frame.size.height

Comment: Do you want the position of the accumulated frame of the SKShapeNode (title) or the position of the sprite node (first sentence)?